# Strategies for implementing a dynamic, extensible search system

Tags: c#, search, dynamic

I wasn't quite sure how to word this question, as this is a field in which I am not very familiar, and I'm seeking less of a specific solution and more of what I should be looking to learn to better understand the problem...

if this is to be closed as a result, please suggest ways I can better express the question as I would very much like to get some input.

Basically the problem is this: I have a several different tables of data, each of which identifies different properties of a user. For example, one table might define a users demographic data (gender, location, etc.), another their interests, and another perhaps their favorite songs.

I want to be able to issue different searches of this data via an application running asp.net mvc, but rather than find specific matches (such as say a song title), I want to be able to do something like "women who like burgers and live in texas".

clearly this is a more dynamic search than just a simple keyword because the criteria can vary both by which data is being searched, what combinations of data is being aggregated, and what actually constitutes a match on each parameter.

If I want to research the different ways something like this can be accomplished, what should I look for? is this something Functional Programming could help resolve? or perhaps dynamic LINQ? i've seen some docs on expression trees which went completely over my head, but looked promising. however I wasn't sure this would fit because the data may change as well (such as new tables being added) and I'm not sure if that is something that needs to be fully defined ahead of time.

What concepts, algorithms and patterns should I explore that might help me create such a system?

I'm happy to learn, but this is something I'm completely in the dark about and don't even know where to begin, so any introductory concepts that I can start exploring would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I just realized I missed one important requirement which is that these searches also need to be saved. so in addition to dynamically searching the data, I also need a way to persist these searches.

the closest thing I can think of that does something like this is say a CRM or Project Management tool which lets you build queries on the fly and save them to be run on demand or on a schedule...

what are some of the strategies that these systems use? the more time i spend researching Dynamic LINQ the better it seems but I'm not sure if I am on the right track.

Comment: I think it should be moved to programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: thanks wasn't aware there was such a thing, is this something I can do or does a mod have to do it?

Comment: I hope that moderators will do it for you.